# Titanium SDK Get Selected ListView item iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Looking to retrieve the selected ListView row at any given time. I know I can keep track of it on click, but there are many scenarios where the "selected" status gets removed. I would like to keep it consistent so that if the row has the selected background color I can get that index.

Right now I'm keeping a variable on click and hunting down all the scenarios where it gets removed (window blur, redraw of the list view). The one I can't find an event for is when you slide the row to show the edit actions. As soon as you start to slide, the row loses its selected background color, but there's no event for that as far as I can tell.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by setting selectionStyle to none, listening for the click and updating the background color manually. This doesn't truly represent the native "selected" status of the row, but works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView has no selected state in Titanium. Not sure if it has natively either.

If the functionality is there natively it could be a great add-on to Titanium, and to help set that in motion you could raise a ticket on the [Appcelerator Jira](http://jira.appcelerator.org) to get that implemented. To expedite even that you could submit a Pull Request to their [open source code on github](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile)

For now you will indeed have to keep track of it through click events and what you describe.

Comment: Thanks, from what I can tell they use a regular table view on iOS behind the scenes. UITableView does indeed have a [method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow?language=objc) to get the selected index path. Would also be nice if they exposed the selection delegate [methods](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview?language=objc). I will raise a ticket.